# Create widget area in wordpress dashboard pages section?

Tags: php, wordpress, admin, dashboard

How to create a widget area in wordpress pages section. if I add below code in my **functions.php** file the widget created in dashboard menu section I want to add additional widget in my pages section not in dashboard.

Add a widget to the dashboard.

```
 //This function is hooked into the 'wp_dashboard_setup' action below.



function example_add_dashboard_widgets() {

wp_add_dashboard_widget(
             'example_dashboard_widget',         // Widget slug.
             'Example Dashboard Widget',         // Title.
             'example_dashboard_widget_function' // Display function.
    );
```

}

```
add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'example_add_dashboard_widgets' );
```

Create the function to output the contents of our Dashboard Widget.

```
function example_dashboard_widget_function() {

// Display whatever it is you want to show.

echo "Hello World, I'm a great Dashboard Widget";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should register sidebar in functions.php as

```
if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) {  
     register_sidebar(array(  
      'name' => 'widget_name',  
      'id'   => 'widget-id',  
      'description'   => 'Type something here',  
      'before_widget' => '<div id="one" class="two">',  
      'after_widget'  => '</div>',  
      'before_title'  => '<h2>',  
      'after_title'   => '</h2>'  
     ));  
    }
```

it will register sidebar(widget) in your dashboard. Now you can you is it anywhere by

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar('widget-id'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This  function already exists in  default theme

```
    function twentyfourteen_widgets_init() {
    require get_template_directory() . '/inc/widgets.php';
    register_widget( 'Twenty_Fourteen_Ephemera_Widget' );

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Primary Sidebar', 'twentyfourteen' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
        'description'   => __( 'Main sidebar that appears on the left.', 'twentyfourteen' ),
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
        'before_title'  => '<h1 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h1>',
    ) );
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Content Sidebar', 'twentyfourteen' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-2',
        'description'   => __( 'Additional sidebar that appears on the right.', 'twentyfourteen' ),
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
        'before_title'  => '<h1 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h1>',
    ) );
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Footer Widget Area', 'twentyfourteen' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-3',
        'description'   => __( 'Appears in the footer section of the site.', 'twentyfourteen' ),
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
        'before_title'  => '<h1 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h1>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'twentyfourteen_widgets_init' );
```

you can create  multiple  widget area   by  copy and pasting this and chage the  id every time

```
register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'new area', 'twentyfourteen' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-5',
        'description'   => __( 'Appears in the footer section of the site.', 'twentyfourteen' ),
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
        'before_title'  => '<h1 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h1>',
    ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In function.php add:

```
function create_widget($name, $id, $description) {

    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => __( $name ),    
        'id' => $id,
        'description' => __( $description ),
        'before_widget' => '<div id="'.$id.'" class="widget %1$s %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3>',
        'after_title' => '</h3>'
    ));

}


    create_widget("Header", "uptop", "Displays in the header of the site, above the title"); // Create the actual widgets
```

Then add next code in place u wanna use this area, for example in your header.php:

```
<?php if ( !dynamic_sidebar('uptop') ); ?>
```